# codigo entra en else if sin cumplirse la condicion

Tags: javascript, html5

tengo el siguiente problema: Estoy haciendo un pequeño programa, para mi mismo, para practicar inglés, lo que se supone que hace es mostrarte una palabra en español, y tu tienes que traducirla al inglés, luego verifica y si es cierto muestra un mensaje típico de success, y si no pues uno de error.

La funcionalidad la cumple :D, lo malo es el mensaje, por ejemplo si la primera vez lo pongo correcto, pues sale el mensaje de correcto, en cambio en la segunda vez si lo pongo correcto, me sale el mensaje de correcto y todo, pero con la clase de error :(, entonces si alguien me puede ayudar :D

pequeña explicacion del código: podría guardar los datos con mysql perfectamente pero que pereza jsjsjs, por eso lo guardo en un array, con Math.random saco un numero aleatorio(con las posciciones de las palabras en español, 0 2 4 6 8 10 y asi), luego se lo paso a la funcion que muestra y verifica, y le paso tambien la respuesta, que seria el numero de la palabra en español + 1, ejemplo: comer es la poscicion 0, y su respuesta pues es 0 +1, osea la poscicion 1 :D...fin de la mini explicacion.

código: (archivo app.js)

```
let english = document.querySelector('#ingles');
let spanish = document.querySelector('#español');
let button = document.querySelector('#button');
let reply = document.querySelector('#respuesta');
let ctnRespuesta = document.querySelector('#ctnRespuesta');

function acertarPalabra(a, b){
    español.innerHTML = a;

    button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        if(english.value == b){
            reply.innerHTML = '¡Correcto!';
            english.value = '';
            ctnRespuesta.classList.add('active');
            setTimeout(()=>{
                ctnRespuesta.classList.remove('active');
            }, 900);
            setTimeout(palabraAleatoria, 600);
            console.log(ctnRespuesta.classList);
        }else if(english.value != b){
            reply.innerHTML = '¡Incorrecto!';
            ctnRespuesta.classList.add('active');
            ctnRespuesta.classList.add('incorrect');
        }
    });
}

let random;

function palabraAleatoria(){
    spanish.innerHTML = '';
    random = parseInt((Math.random() * (vocabulary.length - 1)).toFixed(0));
    while(random%2 !== 0){
        random = parseInt((Math.random() * (vocabulary.length - 1)).toFixed(0));
    }
    acertarPalabra(vocabulary[random], vocabulary[random + 1]);
}

palabraAleatoria();
```

(archivo db.js)

```
const vocabulary = [
    'comer', 'eat',
    'feliz', 'happy',
    'jugar', 'play',
    'interesante', 'interesting',
    'gracioso', 'funny',
    'conocer', 'meet',
    'actor', 'actor',
    'leche', 'milk',
    'parque', 'park'
]
```

(index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla:ital,wght@0,500;1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>English</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="ctn-respuesta" id="ctnRespuesta">
        <p id="respuesta"></p>
    </div>

    <div class="ctn-centrar">
        <h2 id="español"></h2>
        <input type="text" id="ingles" autofocus>
        <button id="button">Comprobar</button>
    </div>
    
</body>
<script src="db.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Uso de `===` y `!==` quizás ??

Comment: Cuando la respuesta es correcta, quita la clase de error: `ctnRespuesta.classList.remove('incorrect');`

Answer (score 0):

Para todos los que vieron esta pregunta, al parecer era pq no puede tener el addEventListener dentro de la funcion, asi que lo puse afuera y todo se solucionó, la verdad nunca me habia pasado eso :(, pero bueno, por lo menos se solucionó :D

Comment: ¿Cada vez que ejecutabas el método, creabas un listener? Es, cuando menos, raro. Me alegra que encontraras la solución :)

Comment: @Alfabravo, si alpareces estaba sobreescribiendo varios listener y eso probocaba ese bug